# vue caddy rule for context path

Tags: vue.js, caddy

I followed vue tutorial for deploying applications with context path as https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath
I used the vue provided caddy rule since i am using history mode https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#caddy

I am using caddy for deployments.

But when i use the publicpath ,and i go for a router configuration which has a /path , its giving me 404. It works fine in locally ;but doesnt work on caddy.

```js
Vue.use(Router)
const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Home },
  { path: '/markabsent/:studentid/:techerid', component: StudentForm, props: true },
  { path: '/markpresent/:studentid/teacher/:techerid', component: StudentReturnForm},
  { path: '*', component: PageNotFound }
]

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: 'univ',
  routes
})
```

I use the default caddy config only as below

```
0.0.0.0:2015

root /var/www/html

log stdout

errors stdout

rewrite {
    regexp .*
    to {path} /
}
```

when i access myapp.com/univ/markpresent/43/343 . , its 404. When i access ,myapp.com/univ/ ,it loads the initial page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting a `basepath` on your [`rewrite`](https://caddyserver.com/docs/rewrite) block and rewrite to `/univ/` (your app's entry point)

```
rewrite /univ {
  r .*
  to {path} /univ/
}
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I don't know Caddy very well</sub>

I've created a feature-request ticket asking for the documentation to include non-root `publicPath` setups.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2863

---

#### Vue Setup

I just used the default `vue create` app with the default routes plus some minor  modification

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/univ'
}
```

```js
// src/router.js
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL, //  this gets the value from publicPath
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/about/:studentid/:techerid',
      name: 'about',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

and in the `About.vue` template, I added

```html
<pre>params = {{ $route.params }}</pre>
```

I then built the app with `npm run build` and copied the `dist` folder contents to a `univ` directory in my Caddy web root.

Directly opening `http://localhost:2015/univ/about/332/2342` in the browser shows the following

[image: about page]

Comment: hm..how about static assets?

Comment: They should be covered by `{path}`

Comment: its getting redirected to index.html completely , the component marked against the route is not loading :-(

Comment: What is _"it"_ in that sentence? Try `to {path} /univ/` instead (I'll update my answer)

Comment: the request to /univ/markabsent/332/2342 is completely getting redirected to /univ/ and home component is getting rendered

Comment: Thanks..it works when root url is accessed..it doesn't work when a route is accessed

Comment: @Janier I've just tried locally with Caddy and my answer works correctly. Make sure you're restarting Caddy and also try clearing your browser cache

Comment: Did you try for a component in a route.

Comment: Like map a route to component and componet is getting rendered against that route

Comment: Could it be problem with vue router then?do you hav to give contxt root in vue router ?

Comment: Can you share your vue configs as well

Comment: the trailing slash in `/univ/` on `to {path} /univ/` is crucial, otherwise you get redirected to `/univ`.