# npm build a vue app and run it on a raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, raspberry-pi

I am creating a Vue app with my roommate and we want to deploy it on our raspberry Pi.
Is there a possibility to npm build our final app on our PC and just start the server on the Pi without having to build the app on the Raspberry? And if so, how can we start the app on the Raspberry?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: when building, does the build process output the built project somewhere (in my experience with vuejs, it's usually the `dist` folder .... that's what you want to copy to the pi) - the app doesn't run on the pi as such though, you just need a http server running on the pi, configured correctly - popular choices for http server are Apache and Nginx - but a very simple server is all you need, even some python or nodejs based will perform adequately - up to you what you use to serve your project

Comment: Okay right now i only have node installed on the Pi. So i just navigate to that location and "npm start"?

Comment: well, no, that's nothing like what I said, clearly the terminology is confusing you - vue projects produce html, javascript and css (along with images etc) ... but a vue project isn't an app in the sense that it is executable, it's basically web pages - so, for that, you need a browser - so, for that, you need a http server as mentioned in the previous comment

Comment: You have node installed so you can use the [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) package to serve static folder content. Create a suitable folder like `/home/username/myapp` and copy the `dist` or `build` files in there. Then do `npx serve`. If apache is already installed on the Pi, you should have a `/var/www/html` folder. Put the built files in there and just visit the Pi's IP address in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally possible. Build your vue app on your PC (known as development environment) and host it on you raspberry pi (production environment). There multiple ways to do this, but from a high level perspective you just need to:

1. Set up you pi like normal by installing the preferred OS
2. SSH into the pi from your PC
3. Install a webserver. For Vue a quick fix could either be Nginx or Apache
4. You can install both Node and Git on the webserver through SSH. Then you can `git clone` the app right into the correct folder. Then with Node installed on the server you can run your `npm` commands like normal and build the Vue site on the server with `npm run build`. Otherwise you can just copy your build/dist folder to the server, but then you might need to do some extra configuration.
5. Get a domain name and point it to your raspberry pi's IP (https://www.noip.com/ is a good free choice I think)

A good list of tutorials to follow is:

1. How to set up SSH on a raspberri pi
2. How to set up Nginx or Apache on a raspberri pi
3. How to deploy a Vue app to a webserver (check both Nginx and Apache). There are some good videos on youtube to check out
4. Pointing a domain name to my raspberry pi website

**NB:** One last very important thing to remember is that if you're going to expose your webserver to the internet via your home network (using your own internet at home), you might expose your router to the world, which could enable malicious actors to get into your PC and any other device connected to your network. You might need to think about installing a firewall to prevent this. So maybe check out some research on that too.

Here are some useful links:
https://www.instructables.com/Host-your-website-on-Raspberry-pi/
https://medium.com/@thesabareesh/host-your-own-website-on-a-raspberry-pi-3-e3c8fdb90f90

Comment: A domain name might be going a bit far. Also, you don't just _"point"_ a domain name to an IP, you need to configure DNS for that

Comment: @Phil configure DNS ... point an IP ... six of one, fifty cents of the other :p

Comment: `check both Nginx and Apache` for the brave, check caddyserver

Comment: @Bravo requires nameservers, editing the registrar, etc, etc. My point was it's not super simple and two roomies with the same `/etc/hosts` entries would be much easier. Also, I found Caddy very simple to use. Even managed to [answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57300360/283366) with zero prior experience

Comment: Totally @Phil. This is just a high level overview.

Comment: Oooo @Bravo, caddyserver looks very interesting! Thanks for that. Something new for me to explore! Totally agree though. Nginx and Apache can get tricky.

Comment: #1 reason I like caddyserver - virtually zero setup to get letsencrypt certs - the config you need ... an email address ... one single config item and it's done! #2 reason - http3 support

Answer (score 1):

The result of a vanilla Vue build is a `dist` directory containing static files.

You can serve them over the network using a static file server: Nginx or Apache for example. The latter I believe is preinstalled in the Raspberry Pi OS and a lot of other distros.

You can also follow [this guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#1-overview) as a starting point for Apache.
Also the Vue docs have a [page dedicated to deployment](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html).

Comment: Apache is thankfully NOT preinstalled on Pi